# Custom permalink with custom taxonomies for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I need to rewrite urls of my custom post type from:
**/post_type_slug/post_type_name**
to
**/post_type_taxonomy_terms1+post_type_taxonomy_terms2/post_type_name**
Attached code works fine: url are correctly rewrited BUT I have a 404.
Note:
elementi = post type name
company_cat = custom taxonomy

```
// ===================================================================
// CATEGORIA ITEM TAXONOMY
// ===================================================================


if ( ! function_exists( 'company_cat' ) ) {

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function company_cat() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Categorie item', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'adverman' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Categoria item', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'adverman' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'Tutte le categorie', 'adverman' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Categoria item genitore', 'adverman' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Categoria item genitore:', 'adverman' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nuova Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Aggiungi nuova Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Modifica Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Aggiorna Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'Guarda Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separe le Categoria item con la virgola', 'adverman' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Aggiungi o rimuovi Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Scegli tra le più usate', 'adverman' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Categorie item frequenti', 'adverman' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Cerca Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Non trovata', 'adverman' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'Nessuna Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Lista Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Navigazione lista Categoria item', 'adverman' ),
    );
    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                       => 'elementi',
        'with_front'                 => true,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => false,
        'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
        'query_var'                  => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'company_cat', array( 'elementi' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'company_cat', 0 );

}


// ====================================================================
// ELEMENTI POST TYPE
// ====================================================================

if ( ! function_exists('elementi') ) {

// Register Custom Post Type
function elementi() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Elementi', 'Post Type General Name', 'adverman' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Elemento', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'adverman' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Archivio elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Attributi elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Elemento genitore:', 'adverman' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'Tutti gli elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Aggiungi nuovo elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Aggiungi nuovo', 'adverman' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'Nuovo elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Modifica elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Aggiorna elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'Vedi elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'Vedi elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Cerca elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Non trovato', 'adverman' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Non trovato nel cestino', 'adverman' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Immagine in evidenza', 'adverman' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Imposta immagine in evidenza', 'adverman' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Rimuovi immagine in evidenza', 'adverman' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Usa come immagine in evidenza', 'adverman' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Inserisci nell\'elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Caricati in questo elemento', 'adverman' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Lista elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Navigazione lista elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filtra lista elementi', 'adverman' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'elementi', 'adverman' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type per elementi generici', 'adverman' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'city','company_cat' ),
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 6,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-pressthis',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'show_in_rest'          => false,
        'rewrite'               => array('slug' => 'elementi/%company_cat%', 'with_front' => false),
        'query_var'             => true,
    );
    register_post_type( 'elementi', $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
add_action( 'init', 'elementi', 0 );

}


function item_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( 'elementi' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, 'elementi/%company_cat%' ) ) {
            $item_type_term = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'company_cat' );

            $item_type_term_parent_def = array();
            // Only terms parents
            foreach ($item_type_term as $item_type_term_parent_obj) {
                if ($item_type_term_parent_obj->parent == 0){
                    array_push($item_type_term_parent_def, $item_type_term_parent_obj->slug);
                }
            }
            $item_type_term = implode("+", $item_type_term_parent_def);
            $post_link = str_replace( 'elementi/%company_cat%', $item_type_term, $post_link );
        }
        return $post_link;
    }
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'item_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Try flushing the rewrite rules. Settings->permalinks and save changes (no need to actually change anything).

Comment: Tried many times, but nothing happen!

Comment: Look at the contents of `$wp_query` in the template and you will see what WP is trying to query for. Also- don't forget to remove `flush_rewrite_rules` from your `init` action, that should only happen once when they change.

Comment: I'va partially solved, setting 'false' to rewrite param of taxonomy... but I must still add a custom post type slug in the url to avoid 404... now it works with url: post_type_slug/post_type_taxonomy_terms1+post_type_taxonomy_terms2/post_type_name 
if I remove post_type_slug I still have 404

Comment: There are many other questions here about removing the post type slug if you search around. The problem you will have is that those rules will clash with the built in `page` post type rules.

Comment: Antonio have you tried to debug your url (for matching rewrite rule ) and query vars you getting from it (based on query vars you got from query wp quering posts and if no posts found it will generate 404)?